# No audio through HDMI in 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, hdmi

I’ve just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS onto my old desktop that was running Win7 and everything seems to be working great aside from my audio. I have the computer plugged into my tv with HDMI however the audio won’t play through my tv speakers. When I go into sound settings the only option I get is Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio and no option to change it to the HDMI. If I plug in a set of headphones the audio does work on them. I’ve tried a few articles that I’ve found that touched on the issue however none of them have worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try pavucontrol - PulseAudio Volume Control
It's in Ubuntu Software twice, one is GTK and one is QT. You'll want the GTK version if you have stock Ubuntu and aren't using any other desktop environment.

Comment: I’ve just installed the GTK version and it is displaying Digital Stereo HDMI Output as being unplugged